# Linear combination with unknown integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose I have three vectors,$$\mathbf{u}=<1,3,-4,0,1>\\\mathbf{v}=<4,-1,0,0,-3>\\\mathbf{w}=<-4,3,-2,x-2y,2x>$$ where *x* and *y* are integers. How could I find the value of *x* and *y* so that **w** would be a linear combination of **u** and **v**?

Comment: Notice that $x-2y$ has to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

So you want $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that
$$\mathbf{w}=\alpha \mathbf{u}+\beta \mathbf{v}.$$
This gives a system of equation :
\begin{cases}
-4 = \alpha +4\beta  \\
3 = 3\alpha -\beta\\
-2=-4\alpha \\
x-2y = 0\\
2x = \alpha -3\beta
\end{cases}
The three first equations show you that you can't have $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\mathbf{w}=\alpha \mathbf{u}+\beta \mathbf{v}.$
Therefore, there is no $x,y$ as wanted.